# python: getting rid of values from a list

Tags: python

```
drug_input=['MORPHINE','CODEINE']    
def some_function(drug_input)      
      generic_drugs_mapping={'MORPHINE':0,
                                'something':1,
                                'OXYCODONE':2,
                                'OXYMORPHONE':3,
                                'METHADONE':4,
                                'BUPRENORPHINE':5,
                                'HYDROMORPHONE':6,
                                'CODEINE':7,
                                'HYDROCODONE':8}
```

`row` is a list.

I would like to set all the members of `row[..]=''` EXCEPT for those that `drug_input` defines, in this case it is 0, and 7.

So `row[1,2,3,4,5,6,8]=''`

If `row` is initially:

```
row[0]='blah'
row[1]='bla1'
...
...
row[8]='bla8'
```

I need:

```
row[0]='blah' (same as before)
row[1]=''
row[2]=''
row[3]=''
...
...
row[7]='bla7'
row[8]=''
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Don't use a list.  Use a dictionary.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking for.  What should the full value of `row` be in the end, precisely?  What should the values that aren't empty strings be?

Comment: You are almost definitely Doing It Wrong. Sparse is better than dense.

Comment: sorry, updated my question it was not so clear before

Comment: Still don't understand why you need a row that contains so many empty values. Why don't you just keep a list of the numbers you **do** want, like `[0, 7]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could first create a set of all the indexes that should be kept, and then set all the other ones to `''`:

```
keep = set(generic_drugs_mapping[drug] for drug in drug_input)
for i in range(len(row)):
  if i not in keep:
    row[i] = ''
```

Comment: @I__: `range` is a standard library function that returns a list of numbers, from 0 to the one given as parameter (exclusive). Like `range(5)` == `[0,1,2,3,4]`. See http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#range

Comment: If `len(row)` is large I'd use `xrange` instead of `range`; it works the same in a for loop but avoids actually building the list in memory.

Answer (score 2):

I'd set up a `defaultdict` unless you *really* need it to be a list:

```
from collections import defaultdict # put this at the top of the file

class EmptyStringDict(defaultdict):
    __missing__ = lambda self, key: ''

newrow = EmptyStringDict()
for drug in drug_input:
    keep = generic_drugs_mapping[drug]       
    newrow[keep] = row[keep]
saved_len = len(row) # use this later if you need the old row length
row = newrow
```

Having a list that's mostly empty strings is wasteful.  This will build an object that returns `''` for every value except the ones actually inserted.  However, you'd need to change any iterating code to use `xrange(saved_len)`.   Ideally, though, you would just modify the code that uses the list so as not to need such a thing.

If you really want to build the list:

```
newrow = [''] * len(row) # build a list of empty strings
for drug in drug_input:
    keep = generic_drugs_mapping[drug]       
    newrow[keep] = row[keep] # fill it in where we need to
row = newrow # throw the rest away
```

Comment: Okay, I've updated my answer to answer your question better now.